# How to multiply and add two fields in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to multiply and add two fields in jasper report(where one field is float and another one is integer)

Thanks

Comment: I can't run jasper here but you can try something like : (new String()).format("%d", ($F{parameter1}*$F{parameter2}))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample:

```xml
<parameter name="floatParam" class="java.lang.Float"/>
<parameter name="intParam" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
...
<textField pattern="#,##0.00;-#,##0.00">
    <reportElement key="result" x="98" y="3" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{floatParam}*$P{intParam}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply/add float+int, the result will be `float`. So you cannot use `"%d"`

```
(new String()).format("%d", ($F{parameter1}*$F{parameter2}))
```

Use `"%f"` instead:

```
new String().format("%f", ($F{parameter1}*$F{parameter2}))
```